# How do I git rm a file without deleting it from disk?

Tags: git, git-rm

The command removes the file in my system. I meant it to remove only the file from Git-repository.

How can I remove the file from a Git repository, without removing the file in my system?

Comment: remove it from previous commits or from the last one?

Comment: @Nick D. The question let it open.

Answer (score 708, accepted):

```
git rm --cached file
```

should do what you want.

You can read more details at `git help rm`

Comment: I'm new to Git, but I've done this a few times and then when someone else pulls from the repository, *their* local file is deleted.  Still searching to see if way to not delete from next developer that does a pull.

Comment: @Terry, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604625/git-how-to-remove-file-from-index-without-deleting-files-from-any-repository

Comment: The confusing thing for me is that the man page for git-rm says that it doesn't remove the file(s) from your working directory. But what I see when I don't use --cached is that the file is remved.

Comment: Wait so... if I do: git rm --cached . 

It will remove all the files shown to be deleted in my git status?

Comment: @gran_profaci Presumably that would mark all the files in the current directory as deleted in the repository index without actually deleting the files from the working tree.

Comment: Presumably is not a nice word when all you run the risk of all your  files being deleted :)

Comment: @gran_profaci The presumably was mainly because `git rm` has a `-r` flag to indicate recursive deletes when you give it a directory name like `.`. It isn't a question of whether things will be marked deleted, it's a question of which (or any) things. And `--cached` doesn't actually delete anything. It just marks it as having been done.

Comment: Ah... thanks a lot for clarifying that! Much appreciated...

Comment: I just tested this and it does delete the file from disk

Comment: This option should be the default behavior

Answer (score 37):

I tried experimenting with the answers given. My personal finding came out to be:

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

And then

```
git add .
```

This seemed to make my working directory nice and clean. You can put your fileName in place of the dot.

Comment: +1 `-r`: Allow recursive removal when a leading directory name is given.

Comment: -r is not required if you do *.suffix (very disturbing to discover this behavior the hard way)

Comment: `-r` for directories is what was needed.