# Git: How to remove file from index without deleting files from any repository

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore, git-rm

When you use

```
git rm --cached myfile
```

it doesn't delete from the local filesystem, which is the goal. But if you've already versioned and committed the file, pushed it to a central repository, and pulled it into yet another repository before using the command, it will delete the file from that system.

Is there a way to just remove the file from versioning without deleting it from any filesystem?

Edit: Clarified, I hope.

Comment: Perhaps you could expand on your use case. The index is the staging area for the next commit so why do you want to remove the file from the index if you don't want to remove it from the current branch?

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant to say myfile has for some reason been commited and distributed a long time ago. Now the goal is to remove it from versioning without deleting it from people's systems.

The reason this came up is because I accidentally versioned a config file. The config file is necessary, so I don't want to remove it from foreign systems.

Comment: I've edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: git rm --cached will not remove the file from the other working directory.  The file will only be removed if someone working in that directory executes a pull.  The file can easily be recovered with "git checkout HEAD@{1} foo" (if executed immediately after the pull.)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

I do not think a Git commit can record an intention like “stop tracking this file, but do not delete it”.

Enacting such an intention will require intervention outside Git in any repositories that merge (or rebase onto) a commit that deletes the file.

---

### Save a Copy, Apply Deletion, Restore

Probably the easiest thing to do is to tell your downstream users to save a copy of the file, pull your deletion, then restore the file.
If they are pulling via rebase and are ‘carrying’ modifications to the file, they will get conflicts. To resolve such conflicts, use `git rm foo.conf && git rebase --continue` (if the conflicting commit has changes besides those to the removed file) or `git rebase --skip` (if the conflicting commit has only changed to the removed file).

### Restore File as Untracked After Pulling a Commit That Deletes It

If they have already pulled your deletion commit, they can still recover the previous version of the file with [*git show*](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html):

```
git show @{1}:foo.conf >foo.conf
```

Or with [*git checkout*](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) (per comment by William Pursell; but remember to re-remove it from the index!):

```
git checkout @{1} -- foo.conf && git rm --cached foo.conf
```

If they have taken other actions since pulling your deletion (or they are pulling with rebase into a detached HEAD), they may need something other than `@{1}`. They could use `git log -g` to find the commit just before they pulled your deletion.

---

In a comment, you mention that the file you want to “untrack, but keep” is some kind of configuration file that is required for running the software (directly out of a repository).

### Keep File as a ‘Default’ and Manually/Automatically Activate It

If it is not completely unacceptable to continue to maintain the configuration file's content in the repository, you might be able to rename the tracked file from (e.g.) `foo.conf` to `foo.conf.default` and then instruct your users to `cp foo.conf.default foo.conf` after applying the rename commit.
Or, if the users already use some existing part of the repository (e.g. a script or some other program configured by content in the repository (e.g. `Makefile` or similar)) to launch/deploy your software, you could incorporate a defaulting mechanism into the launch/deploy process:

```
test -f foo.conf || test -f foo.conf.default &&
    cp foo.conf.default foo.conf
```

With such a defaulting mechanism in place, users should be able to pull a commit that renames `foo.conf` to `foo.conf.default` without having to do any extra work.
Also, you avoid having to manually copy a configuration file if you make additional installations/repositories in the future.

### Rewriting History Requires Manual Intervention Anyway…

If it is unacceptable to maintain the content in the repository then you will likely want to completely eradicate it from history with something like [`git filter-branch --index-filter …`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch).
This amounts to rewriting history, which will require manual intervention for each branch/repository (see “Recovering From Upstream Rebase” section in the [*git rebase* manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)).
The special treatment required for your configuration file would be just another step that one must perform while recovering from the rewrite:

1. Save a copy of the configuration file.
2. Recover from the rewrite.
3. Restore the configuration file.

---

### Ignore It to Prevent Recurrence

Whatever method you use, you will probably want to include the configuration filename in a `.gitignore` file in the repository so that no one can inadvertently `git add foo.conf` again (it is possible, but requires `-f`/`--force`).
If you have more than one configuration file, you might consider ‘moving’ them all into a single directory and ignoring the whole thing (by ‘moving’ I mean changing where the program expects to find its configuration files, and getting the users (or the launch/deploy mechanism) to copy/move the files to to their new location; you obviously would not want to *git mv* a file into a directory that you will be ignoring).

Comment: Incredibly thorough response. Thank you!

Comment: Tom Power's answer, below, appears to contradict your first sentence.

Comment: @MikeS: The effect of `--{,no-}assume-unchanged` is purely local: its state is not directly recorded in commits. It can help prevent a repository from committing new changes to the file, but it does not remove it from version control. If you can set it for all your relevant, related, non-bare repositories, then it may help your situation, but it is not something that you could *directly* push+pull/rebase into other related, non-bare repositories (especially ones that you do not control, as per the original asker’s clarifying comments on the question: see “people's systems”/“foreign systems”).

Comment: `I do not think a Git commit can record an intention like “stop tracking this file, but do not delete it”.` - now it can, with `git rm --cached foo.conf`

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Doesn’t the question already indicate that this is inadequate for the asker’s purpose: (automatically) keeping the file around when the resulting commit is pulled into another repository?

Comment: I might be doing something wrong, but I just tried the "Save a Copy, Apply Deletion, Restore" approach and every time I checkout that branch it deletes the file again. So I would have to restore it after every checkout which is a bit painful?

Answer (score 92):

Had the very same issue this week when I accidentally committed, then tried to remove a build file from a shared repository, and this:

http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/18/temporarily-ignoring-files.html

has worked fine for me and not mentioned so far.

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

To remove the file you're interested in from version control, then use all your other commands as normal.

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

If you ever wanted to put it back in.

Edit: please see comments from Chris Johnsen and KPM, this only works locally and the file remains under version control for other users if they don't also do it. The accepted answer gives more complete/correct methods for dealing with this. Also some notes from the link if using this method:

> Obviously there’s quite a few caveats that come into play with this.
>   If you git add the file directly, it will be added to the index.
>   Merging a commit with this flag on will cause the merge to fail
>   gracefully so you can handle it manually.

Comment: This is not an answer for the specific problem mentioned. It will only work for your own local repository, so each user has to do this himself. It's a pain.

Answer (score 37):

1. `git rm --cached remove_file`
2. add file to gitignore
3. `git add .gitignore`
4. `git commit -m "Excluding"`
5. Have fun ;)

Comment: This is the easiest.

Comment: @Julien my thoughts exactly, not sure why the accepted answer had to be a doctoral thesis

Comment: @lasec0203 Because like this Git will still delete the file for everyone else as soon as they pull. And the question is how to get something out of the index without deleting it on pull. Something that seems to be close to impossible.

Comment: This works for transferring dependencies from version control to a package manager. In this case, a build process should install the dependencies after pulling the repository - as should any other developers working on the project - so you shouldn't need to worry about the files being missing on other worktrees.

Answer (score 34):

To remove the file from the index, use:

```
git reset mylife
```

This should not affect your local copy or anyone else's.

Comment: `reset` only removes the file from the index if the file isn't in the current HEAD commit, otherwise it just reverts the index version to the current HEAD version.

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood the question, but it seems to relate to removing a file from the index without affecting any commits.

Comment: As Charles said, reset does not "remove a file". Type  git help reset  for more info.

Comment: This answers the question as titled "How to remove file from index without deleting files from any repository".  Although the OP really was asking "How do I untrack a file with out deleting the local copy."

Comment: @hewsonism the OP did say "any filesystem" (even before any edits).

Comment: @jbobbins This is true, my comment was purely about the wording of the title.

Answer (score 17):

After doing the `git rm --cached` command, try adding `myfile` to the `.gitignore` file (create one if it does not exist).  This should tell git to ignore `myfile`.

The `.gitignore` file is versioned, so you'll need to commit it and push it to the remote repository.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to pull on the other working copy and then do:

```
git log --pretty="format:" --name-only -n1 | xargs git checkout HEAD^1
```

which says get all the file paths in the latest comment, and check them out from the parent of HEAD. Job done.

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions work fine for most cases.
However, if you also need to remove all traces of that file (ie sensitive data such as passwords), you will also want to remove it from your entire commit history, as the file could still be retrieved from there.

Here is a solution that removes all traces of the file from your entire commit history, as though it never existed, yet keeps the file in place on your system.

https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/

You can actually skip to step 3 if you are in your local git repository, and don't need to perform a dry run.  In my case, I only needed steps 3 and 6, as I had already created my .gitignore file, and was in the repository I wanted to work on.

To see your changes, you may need to go to the GitHub root of your repository and refresh the page. Then navigate through the links to get to an old commit that once had the file, to see that it has now been removed. For me, simply refreshing the old commit page did not show the change.

It looked intimidating at first, but really, was easy and worked like a charm ! :-)