# How to avoid deleting local files when igoring and deleting files on a Github repository?

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitignore

Suppose I have an existing Github repository and several local clones of this repository.

Now I decided to prevent a certain file from being managed by Git and delete the file from the Github repository.  I executed the following commands in one of the local clones:

```
echo "to_be_ignored_file_name" >> .gitignore
git add .
git commit -m 'make git ignore a certain file'

git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "delete the file to be ignored from the repository"

git push origin
```

After the above was done, the file got deleted from the Github repository and Git will be ignoring the file from now on.  But as a result, the local copy of the file also got deleted (for other clones, the file was deleted after `git fetch origin` and `git pull`).

If I replaced the second part of the above command sequence as below:

```
git rm --cached to_be_ignored_file_name
git commit -m "delete the file to be ignored from the repository"

git push origin
```

Then the local file in the clone where the command sequence was executed was untouched, but the same file in other clones still got deleted after `git fetch origin` and `git pull`.

Is there a way to keep the local file untouched in all clones while ignoring and deleting the file from Github repository?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible. See [Git: How to remove file from index without deleting files from any repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604625/git-how-to-remove-file-from-index-without-deleting-files-from-any-repository)

Also consider `git-lock` from [git-extras](https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/master/bin/git-lock), or using `git update-index --skip-worktree` directly instead of deleting from the repository, to ignore local changes if this is something like a config file.