# Git deleting .gitignore files on merge?

Tags: git, git-merge, gitignore

I am trying to follow this [workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow).
But I am having issues. Here's the deal:
I started my repo with master tracking some files.
Immediately I branched into a develop branch.
I later learned that those files should not be tracked (Wordpress core files...I'm learning) so I added them to the .gitignore file.
Now, I am ready for a release, so I branched off into a release for some fine tuning.

So the situation is this: Master is still tracking the files(it only has a single commit).  And release/1.0 is not tracking the files.

Now I am trying to merge my release branch back into master, but when I do that it deletes all my untracked files, instead of just leaving them be.

This is what I'm trying:

```
git checkout master
git merge release/1.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did that worked:

1. In master I modified the .gitignore file to reflect the .gitignore file in release/1.0 and committed.
2. Removed the same files from tracking that I added to .gitignore, using `git rm --cached <file>` and committed again.
3. Then I did the merge successfully.

**Update:** After better understanding the whole situation I was able to google more precisely and found a better worded question and answer here on SO: [Git: How to remove file from index without deleting files from any repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604625/git-how-to-remove-file-from-index-without-deleting-files-from-any-repository)

Although it is talking about different repos and not different branches like I dealt with, I believe the issue is the same.

Answer (score 0):

One of your commits deleted these files. So a straightforward merge will only apply this commit and delete the files. Instead you could do

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff --no-commit release/1.0
git checkout HEAD <deleted-files>
git commit
```

This way you force a merge commit and halt before commiting.
Maybe you should also remove the files from `.gitignore` again.

Now these files are only traked by the `master` branch again and every successive merge should work just fine.

Comment: I think the files are also supposed to be no longer tracked on master, -- so I think either of `git rm --cached -- <deleted-files>` or,  instead of checkout, doing `git show HEAD $path > $path` for each, needs doing here.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember `.gitignore` simply specifies that `git` shouldn't propose ignored files as untracked or modified in the `git status` output. If you add them manually *they will be tracked* as usual. And vice versa: if you remove some files in a branch and then try to merge that branch back to its origin, (this is the situation you are in, I think), then git will remove those files on merge.

Here's the example:

```
alex@galene ~/tmp/tmp5 $ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/alex/tmp/tmp5/.git/
alex@galene ~/tmp/tmp5 $ echo "initial" >file    
alex@galene ~/tmp/tmp5 $ echo "some" >file.bad
alex@galene ~/tmp/tmp5 $ git add file*
alex@galene ~/tmp/tmp5 $ git commit -m "initial"
[master (root-commit) c400ed7] initial
  2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
create mode 100644 file
create mode 100644 file.bad
alex@galene ~/tmp/tmp5 $ git checkout -b branch
Switched to a new branch 'branch'
```

change the "payload" file and commit the changes to the `branch`

```
alex@galene ~/tmp/tmp5 $ echo "c" >file
alex@galene ~/tmp/tmp5 $ git commit -m "branch commit" file
[branch 3eba064] branch commit
  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
alex@galene ~/tmp/tmp5 $ echo "*.bad" > .gitignore
alex@galene ~/tmp/tmp5 $ echo "branch change" >file.bad 
alex@galene ~/tmp/tmp5 $ git status 
On branch branch
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
```

Notice that `file.bad` is still tracked

```
     modified:   file.bad

  Untracked files:
   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

     .gitignore

  no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
alex@galene ~/tmp/tmp5 $ git add .gitignore 
alex@galene ~/tmp/tmp5 $ mv file.bad file.bad.copy; git rm -f file.bad; mv file.bad.copy file.bad
rm 'file.bad'
alex@galene ~/tmp/tmp5 $ git status 
On branch branch
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

       new file:   .gitignore
       deleted:    file.bad

 alex@galene ~/tmp/tmp5 $ git commit -m "remove file.bad from version control but leave in the worktree"
 [branch b4c1d42] remove file.bad from version control but leave in the worktree
   2 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
   create mode 100644 .gitignore
   delete mode 100644 file.bad
alex@galene ~/tmp/tmp5 $ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
```

perform a commit to `master`

```
alex@galene ~/tmp/tmp5 $ echo "master change" >file
alex@galene ~/tmp/tmp5 $ git commit -m "master change" file
[master 78142c8] master change
  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
alex@galene ~/tmp/tmp5 $ git merge --no-commit branch
Removing file.bad
Auto-merging file
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
alex@galene ~/tmp/tmp5 $ git status 
On branch master
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")

Changes to be committed:

         new file:   .gitignore
         deleted:    file.bad

 Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

         both modified:   file
```

As you may see on the last step you get the removal of `file.bad` and (expected) conflict in the `file`. So you may store somewhere `file.bad` before the merge (e.g. `cp file.bad file.bad.copy` and then restore it after the merge).