# git ignore a file on both local and server

Tags: git

I have followed these steps to move the folder to git ignore:

1. Adding folder in .gitignore: test/
2. running: `git rm --cached -r -- test/`
3. add and commit & Push to remote

So it made test folder gitignore on local and that test folder still exist which I want.

So now do I need to do same steps on server as well before taking pull.

I am afraid it will delete my test folder on server if I only take pull and do not do the step for cache clear.

Comment: So you want to keep the `test` folder on the git server? What are you trying to achieve by adding it to `.gitignore`?

Comment: I just want to be able to keep it and direct change via ftp whenever needed. not track by git

Comment: Ok, I had understood the "server" to be the remote git server. You mean just another machine on which the code is already there, right?

Comment: yes correct means my live site

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git: How to remove file from index without deleting files from any repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604625/git-how-to-remove-file-from-index-without-deleting-files-from-any-repository)