# Remove file from the repository but keep it locally

Tags: git, gitignore, git-rm

I have a folder which I'd like to remove in my remote repository. I'd like to delete it, but keep the folder in my computer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: Remove a file from the repository without deleting it from the local filesystem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/git-remove-a-file-from-the-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesys)

Comment: Please look at the suggested related questions as you're writing yours - the duplicate was probably one of the first two.

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273108/how-do-i-git-rm-a-file-without-deleting-it-from-disk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove a file from a Git repository without deleting it from the local filesystem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/remove-a-file-from-a-git-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesyste)

Answer (score 828, accepted):

```
git rm --cached -r somedir
```

Will stage the deletion of the directory, but doesn't touch anything on disk. This works also for a file, like:

```
git rm --cached somefile.ext
```

Afterwards you may want to add `somedir/` or `somefile.ext` to your `.gitignore` file so that git doesn't try to add it back.

Comment: And then add the path to .gitignore so git doesn't try to make you add it later.

Comment: Will this result in (files in) the directory being removed when he pulls from the remote?

Comment: Not when he pulls; the files will stay removed locally during the pull's automatic merge process.  After that, a push will cause the files to be removed server-side.

Comment: What happens if I have a third remote? Will the corresponding files get removed in a future pull? I ask because I feel this is quite a common use case, i.e. check some files into the repo, realise at a later date that they diverge between remotes, for good reason, and should never have been in the repo in the first place, want to resolve that by keeping all local checkouts exactly as they are, but removing the files from the repo.

Comment: For single files, you can do `git rm --cached path/to/file`

Comment: @BobbyJack, files will be removed from the third remote upon `git pull` there. (It worked this way for me.)

Answer (score 5):

I would just:

- Move the folder out of your working tree
- `git rm` the folder, commit the change
- Add to `.gitignore` (or `.git/info/excludes`), commit the change
- Move the folder back

Comment: this is not a good solution - what if you have a very large directory?

Comment: probably need to use `git rm -r`

Comment: @loostro just don't move it to another block device. The most file systems will just update the file's inode, and not literally move the entire directory

Comment: This is the "safe" answer, if you're not comfortable enough or trust git enough to use `git rm --cached` ...  (Which is understandable, given how easy it can be to mess things up with git). You could always try `git rm --cached` in a test dir to build your confidence/trust in it ...  But, this _would_ work, at least.