# Unable to run brew update

Tags: git, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I am getting following error:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    share/doc/homebrew/Analytics.md
    share/doc/homebrew/Checksum_Deprecation.md
    share/doc/homebrew/How-to-Create-and-Maintain-a-Tap.md
    share/doc/homebrew/Kickstarter-Supporters.md
    share/doc/homebrew/Maintainers-Avoiding-Burnout.md
    share/doc/homebrew/Node-for-Formula-Authors.md
    share/doc/homebrew/Prose-Style-Guidelines.md
    share/doc/homebrew/Rename-A-Formula.md
    share/doc/homebrew/brew.1.html
    share/doc/homebrew/images/analytics.png
    share/doc/homebrew/images/brew-test-bot-failed-jenkins.png
    share/doc/homebrew/images/brew-test-bot-failed-pr.png
    share/doc/homebrew/images/brew-test-bot-failed-test.png
    share/doc/homebrew/images/brew-test-bot-passed-jenkins.png
    share/doc/homebrew/images/brew-test-bot-passed-pr.png
    share/doc/homebrew/images/brew-test-bot-triggered-pr.png
    share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting
Error: Failure while executing: git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Comment: Would you have any clarifications whether you've done something else before this happened? Moved a directory or files around, changed settings for Homebrew, changed permissions or owner for the respective files, etc? Also, can you try and run `brew doctor` to see if that comes up with any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: Yes, I did a `git add -A` in `/usr/local`. Also prior to that I ran `git stash`

Comment: Simple question: why did you do that? Brew has its git respository in `/usr/local`, so you were changing Homebrew's repo; that will obviously lead to troubles, so there must've been a good reason (or a simple accident) why you did that.

Comment: Just did it by mistake :/ - How should I revert all things?

Comment: I guess you're question has now become "how do I undo 'git add --all'"?

Comment: Run `git rm --cached <file>` for each file listed by Homebrew. See eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/remove-a-file-from-a-git-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesyste and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469741/remove-file-from-the-repository-but-keep-it-locally .

Comment: I did that by doing `git reset HEAD` but error remains there

Comment: `git reset HEAD` won't undo a `git add --all`, as you noticed. You may want to (re)search a bit more before trying things.

Comment: I see this http://imgur.com/o3cRDoS - you say I run `git rm --cached` individually on these files?

Comment: Yes. If you're hesitant, copy one file as a backup, try on one file first, then check with Homebrew if that file still shows up in the error.

Comment: Did you just get that listing in the image after `git reset HEAD`, or was that there before?

Comment: after doing a reset.

Comment: @Evert These are Untracked files hence git rm will not work.

Comment: ... Search around for 'undo git reset HEAD', or simply throw away all of homebrew (`/usr/local`) and re-install.

Comment: how can I just remove `homebrew`?

Comment: It says origin not found??With a non-standard origin, Homebrew won't pull updates from
the main repository. The current git origin is:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/brew.git

Unless you have compelling reasons, consider setting the
origin remote to point at the main repository, located at:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git

Comment: If you have not else but Homebrew installed software in `/usr/local`/, you can just nuke everything under `/usr/local` (including the `.git` directory), and reinstall everything. Annoying, but it'll work. And while you probably can restore the Homebrew git repository properly, that may take some doing and searching that you may not find worth the hassle.

Comment: @Evert There was an uninstall script provided by Brew guys, it took care of it. I reinstalled and so far working fine. Though I am not sure what applications have got screwed up so far.