# Remove file in specified path from git tracking

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [git - removing a file from source control (but not from the source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/git-removing-a-file-from-source-control-but-not-from-the-source)

I have a .DS_Store file that is in the path project/app/assets/javascripts.

How do I remove from this file git tracking?

Comment: `git rm --cached filename`. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273108

Comment: Related: http://www.aorensoftware.com/blog/2011/12/24/death-to-ds_store/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 rm .DS_Store
 git add -A
 git commit -m "getting rid of artifact."
 echo .DS_Store >> .gitignore
 git add -A
 git commit -m "ignoring artifact."
```