# Recover files deleted with git rm --cached

Tags: git, composer-php

I was trying to ignore the changes on `composer.phar` and `composer.phar` files from the staging area (local host). So I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273108/how-do-i-git-rm-a-file-without-deleting-it-from-disk) answer and did:

```
git rm --cached composer.lock 
git rm --cached composer.phar
```

and added:

```
/composer.lock 
/composer.phar
```

to `.gitignore` file. And all seemed to go as expected, as those files were still there, but they weren't followed.

But now, when I try to pull the changes from the server, these files are removed. I don't what to remove those files, just don't follow them. How could I come back or resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well yes, you deleted the file from the index. You first need to get it back. You can either revert the commit which did that with

`git revert sha_key_of_commit_that_deleted_it`

or if you are ok about changing history you just reset your branch to the point before the change with

`git reset sha_key_of_the_commit_where_sky_was_blue`

Then, what you want to do is this to stop the file from receiving any further changes but keeping it the way it is:

`git update-index --assume-unchanged /composer.lock`

Comment: I changed more files in the same commit and I don't want to delete them. What about adding again those files by `git add -f composer.lock composer.phar` and then do `git update-index --assume-unchanged composer.lock composer.phar` and commit?