# How to delete an ignored file from git repository

Tags: git

I have a file (example: src/test.txt) which wasn't ignored before. But I'm ignoring it now (.gitignore on parent folder). If I do a `git clone`, this ignored file is included in the download.

Is there a way to somehow delete this file from git? I've searched the net but found nothing. I'm unsure what search criteria to use.

There are no branches in my repository.

edit: as a test, I created a new repository. ran "git add ." to add all files and then commit and pushed it. I then cloned the new repo and the ignored file is not listed.

Comment: Use `git rm --cached <file>`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi Tim. I just tried that command. then did a git push. I got an "all up to date" message. I then went to my remote host. Performed a git clone and the file is still there. I just confirmed again the file is in my .gitignore.

Comment: as a test, I created a new repository. ran "git add ." to add all files and then commit and pushed it. I then cloned the new repo and the ignored file is not showing.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/remove-a-file-from-a-git-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesyste (or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273108/how-do-i-git-rm-a-file-without-deleting-it-from-disk)

Answer (score 2):

Tim Biegeleisen say the correct way, maybe you forgot the

```
git commit -m 'delete file'
```

and

```
git push
```

after

```
git rm --cached <file>
```

Comment: I've already commited and pushed several changes since I've edited my .gitignore

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you on you original question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541615/how-to-remove-files-that-are-listed-in-the-gitignore-but-still-on-the-repositor